# "design pattern" for CRUD in ADO.NET Entity Framework 4.1

Tags: c#, design-patterns, entity-framework-4

I would like ask you if exist some "design pattern" for CRUD in ADO.NET Entity Framework 4.1.

For example this method load object from DB.

```
private static Project GetObjects(int id)
{
    var connSetting = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ProjectEntities"];
    var conn = new EntityConnection(connSetting.ConnectionString);
    conn.Open();

    using(var contex= new ProjectEntities(conn))
    {
        var project = (from p in contex.Projects
                       where p.ProjectId == id
                       select p).FirstOrDefault();

        contex.Detach(project);

        return project;
    }
}
```

this method do update:

```
private static void UpdateObject(Project obj)
{
    var connSetting = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ProjectEntities"];
    var conn = new EntityConnection(connSetting.ConnectionString);
    conn.Open();

    using (var contex = new ProjectEntities(conn))
    {
        var entity = (Project)contex.GetObjectByKey(obj.EntityKey);
        contex.ApplyCurrentValues(entity.EntityKey.EntitySetName, obj);
        contex.SaveChanges();
    }

}
```

and this method delete object

```
private static void DeleteObject(Project obj)
{
    var connSettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ProjectEntities"];
    var conn = new EntityConnection(connSettings.ConnectionString);
    conn.Open();
    using(var ctx = new ProjectEntities())
    {
        var entity = (Project)ctx.GetObjectByKey(obj.EntityKey);
        ctx.DeleteObject(entity);
        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

I would like have a nice universal class for CRUD with ADO.NET EF in DB...can you help me? Get link with good sample?

Comment: How about repository pattern? have you considered that? Look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/ImplRepositoryPatternEF.aspx) implementation. hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

And what is wrong with your methods if you make them generic?

The answer to your question is subjective because first problem is if your methods are really useful? Simple CRUD is not usually used with EF. EF provides more and CRUD goes against its additional features. Other problem is type of entities you are using. EntityKey is feature of EntityObject based entities - those entities are currently definitely considered as deprecated because whole EF is moving towards DbContext API and POCOs.

So how to make some reusable CRUD methods for POCOs?

Let's define interface for your entities:

```
public interface IEntity 
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Implement this interface in your entities and now you can define simple reusable methods:

```
private static T GetObject<T>(int id) where T : class, IEntity     
{
    using(var context = GetContext())
    {
        // What if you want to load relations as well?
        var entity = (from x in context.CreateObjectSet<T>()
                      where x.Id == id
                      select p).FirstOrDefault();

        // Typical issue - you cannot use neither eager, explicit or lazy 
        // loading
        context.Detach(entity);

        return entity;
    }
}

private static void UpdateObject<T>(T entity) where T : class, IEntity
{
    using (var contex = GetContext())
    {
        // This works for POCOs but for EntityObject based entities you will have
        // to use your approach (combine it with GetObject method to load entity)
        context.Attach(entity);
        context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(entity, EntityState.Modified);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

}

private static void DeleteObject<T>(int id) where T : class, IEntity, new()
{
    using(var context = GetContext())
    {
        // You need only dummy entity with key to perform delete
        T entity = new T { Id = id };
        context.Attach(entity);
        context.DeleteObject(entity);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Notice `GetContext` - you are looking for reusability so start refactoring your reusable methods as well. If you need to use `EntityObject` based entities add EntityObject to constraints of generic type `T` instead of `class`.

Comment: You just solved an old problem of mine :) Some time ago I had a generic method like your `GetObject<T>(int id)` - with the difference that I passed in an `IQueryable<T>` as second parameter and then used this instead of `context.CreateObjectSet<T>` in the method. And I hadn't a `class` constraint, only the `IEntity` constraint. This compiled but was throwing an exception: *"Unable to cast the type 'MyConcreteTypeTName' to type 'IEntity'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting Entity Data Model primitive types."* I grabbed just the old code, added the `class` constraint and it works now!